# Is there a way to set the default font weight in Outlook 2011?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2011

Is there a way to select a specific weight of a given font family to use for new messages, either in the GUI or by directly modifying a preferences file somewhere?

---

There doesn't appear to be a method for selecting a particular font weight in the new message default font dialogue box. For example: I can select Calibri, but not specifically Calibri Light.

[image: default font selection dialog box]

However, once I've started a new message, I can use the drop-down font selection box and select `choose...`, which brings up a totally different dialog that enables me to select `light` from the `typeface` list box.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Outlook plist file.

[image: Location of Outlook 2011 plist file]

Edit the `HTMLWebPrefsIdentifierWebKitStandardFont` key to call out the desired font, e.g.:

```
<key>HTMLWebPrefsIdentifierWebKitStandardFont</key>  
<string>Calibri-Light</string>
```

Comment: Minor note: to see the ~/Library folder in Finder, execute 
"chflags nohidden ~/Library/"

Comment: Even better, you don't need Finder... just execute 

"defaults write com.microsoft.Outlook.plist HTMLWebPrefsIdentifierWebKitStandardFont Calibri-Light"

Something I just realized: on OSX the font is "Calibri-Light" but on Windows its called "Calibri Light" so when people view your emails on Windows, it will look like crap.  I don't understand why they can't be named the same.  It appears OSX (or at least Outlook) uses the font's PostScript name.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have found on Google, there's no way to increase font size, unless you zoom the whole page.

However, if you think that solution would fit your needs, i found this link that sets up a workaround, in order to zoom only some applications.

[Outlook 2011, font too small](http://www.walkmen.net/blog/2011/02/07/microsoft-outlook-2011-for-mac-font-size-too-small-problem-on-27-imac/)

Comment: Not really what I was looking for, as I want to change the default font weight and not the font size, but your answer pointed me to what I needed to change in the Outlook plist file, which I'll included in an answer below. So thatnks.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for how to do this for Outlook 2016 for Mac (since the preference plist isn't used for 2016)

Use defaults on the terminal like so:

```
defaults write com.microsoft.Outlook HTMLWebPrefsIdentifierWebKitStandardFont Font-Weight
```

In my case I wanted Gotham in Book weight so I put Gotham-Book where Font-Weight is.